# How to open a ASCII text graceful

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

It is confusing when I open a file with Python. By the way I'm using python3.4.

First it's a log file (a huge file that is appended to any time), so `iconv` is not possible.

**Info1** `file` is ASCII text.

```
demo git:master ❯ file 1.log 
1.log: ASCII text, with very long lines
```

**Info2** `ipython` opens it with default encoding of 'UTF-8':

```
 In [1]: f = open('1.log')
    In [2]: f.encoding
    Out[2]: 'UTF-8'
```

#### THEN

**First when I `open('1.log', encoding='utf-8', mode='r')`**

> ERROR: *'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb1 in position 6435: invalid start byte*

**Second when I `open('1.log', encoding='ascii', mode='r')`**

> ERROR: *'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 6633: ordinal
>   not in range(128)*

How can I gracefully handle this file with every line read?

This is my demo on github [demo](https://github.com/doomzhou/demo)

Comment: Do you know the actual encoding of your file? Considering that it contains the 0xE9 byte it's definitely *not* an ASCII file.

Comment: You can use [file magic](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/filemagic/1.6) for Python to get more information about the file you're using and its encoding.

Comment: @dlask it's F5 weblog, i really don't know which encoding. does `file` command just detect begin of file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a few different combinations of encodings and I was able to get all the way through the log file by simply changing the encoding in your script to `latin1`, so the line `open('1.log', encoding='utf-8', mode='r')` becomes `open('1.log', encoding='latin1', mode='r')`.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably Windows CP 1252 or Latin 1. Try opening it with:

```
open('1.log', encoding='latin-1', 'rU')
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its not an ascii file. The encoding test is usually inaccurate. try [chardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) which will detect the encoding for you.

Then

```
import chardet

filepointer = open(self.filename)
charset_detected = chardet.detect(filepointer.read())
```

**Keep in mind that this can take a very very long time.** Before you try that I recommend you manually cycle through the obvious encodings first.

Try UTF16 and UTF32. Then try the Windows encodings. [Here is a list of several encodings.](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml)